# Xml serialization of derived classes not known until runtime

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I am currently implementing a tool that processes Xml files conforming to a standard Xml schema. So far I have generated classes from the schema which use Xml serialization attributes and i am using [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) for deserializing, and for the standard schema that works fine.

However, the schema has various extension points, and those extensions are not known until runtime. A simplified example of this might look like this:

```
// ==== In main assembly ====

public class DeclarationRealisation 
{
    public DataType dataType { get; set; }
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(String)), XmlInclude(typeof(Integer))]  
public abstract class DataType : ExtensionInterface { /* ... */ }

// ==== In extension assembly ====

public class Struct : DataType { /* ... */ }
```

`Struct` has its own xsd file importing the main xsd.
If I put `Struct` into the main assembly, it all works well, even without the `XmlInclude` attribute (maybe [sgen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240(v=vs.110).aspx) does this). But if I put `Struct` into its own assembly (the way we will handle extensions), I get an `InvalidOperation` stating that "the specified type was not recognized". As the extensions are loaded at runtime, i cannot use `XmlInclude`.

I have read about the possibility of implementing [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx), but I would prefer to avoid doing this manually, as it's quite a lot of classes. So, my questions are these:

- Is there a way to achieve this extensibility without having to implement `IXmlSerializable`?
- If not, are there tools/code generators that can handle scenarios like this (either by generating the interface or any other way)?

*Note: I know you can specify extra types when creating XmlSerializers, but the startup hit of automatically generated XmlSerializers (in my case > 3 sec without extensions) is a bit much for my use case and i'd like to avoid it.*

**EDIT:** Thinking about it, it might be acceptable if the performance hit occurs once during the first startup. Is there any way to generate serialization assemblies at runtime? I once heard sgen is just a commandline client to some framework classes, but I can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out the > 3 seconds performance hit was because i used a generic `Deserialize<T>` method to generate matching serializers on demand. Even though i cached them, a new serializer was generated every time I passed a new type, including code generation and compilation, which accumulated.

So now I create a `List<Type>` of all types that i will deserialize using this method, and add all extension types to it, then I generate all required serializers in one go:

```
var deserializedTypes = new List<Type> {
    typeof(DeclarationRealisation) // ...etc...
};

foreach (var extensionType in extensionTypes) { // Includes Struct and more
    deserializedTypes.Add(extensionType);
}

var generatedSerializers = XmlSerializer.FromTypes(deserializedTypes.ToArray());
for (int i = 0; i < generatedSerializers.Length; i++) {
    var xmlType = deserializedTypes[i];
    var serializer = generatedSerializers[i];
    serializers[xmlType] = serializer;
}
```

Using this approach the startup hit reduced to ~0.45 seconds, which is somewhat acceptable.

It would really be awesome if I could now somehow save the generated assembly to use it on subsequent startups, but it seems the generated assembly of type `InternalAssemblyBuilder` provides no way to save it (I would be thankful for any hints on this). But for now, this is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify all types in the second parameter of [XmlSerializer constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5aakyae(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DeclarationRealisation), new Type[] { typeof(Struct) });

DeclarationRealisation result;
using (var reader = new StreamReader("Test.xml"))
{
    result = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as DeclarationRealisation;
}
```

Comment: If the OP is packaging the `Struct` class in a seperate assembly, it can be loaded at runtime using MEF and the `Type` obtained by reflection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know of that possibility, but unfortunately using that constructor causes the runtime to generate a serialization assembly, which is quite a performance hit in my case.